# How to get index of filtered array?

Tags: reactjs

How do i filter the categoryName and header, then get the index of tabs that contains the header?
Example, I have an array of data.

```
const data = [
  {
    categoryName: "Mexican Food",
    tabs: [
      {
        header: "Nachos"
      },  
      {
        header: "Tacos"
      }, 
    ]
  }
]
```

Example, if the input given is const categoryName = "Mexican Food" & const header = "Tacos", once filtered, the index would be 1.

```
Output = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.findIndex(el=>el.categoryName === "Mexican Food"&& el.tabs.find(tb=>tb.header === "Tacos"))
```

The index will be 0 because the first index of the array is 0

Output = 0

Comment: Oh i mean the index of the tabs array that contains "Tacos". It should be index = 1 right? @Francis Fernandes